# openprinting key for ubuntu 18

Tags: apt, 18.04, printing, keyrings, signature

I'm trying to add openprinting repo (http://www.openprinting.org/download/printdriver/debian lsb3.2) to my computer for some reason the key I downloaded (Release.gpg) is not working. I keep getting this error:
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.

Also when I try to update without the key I get this:
W: GPG error: http://www.openprinting.org/download/printdriver/debian lsb3.2 Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 24CBF5474CFD1E2F

So I try to add the key by doing:
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver pgp.key-server.io --recv-keys 24CBF5474CFD1E2F

The Result:
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.NPs0VC8DiH/gpg.1.sh --keyserver pgp.key-server.io --recv-keys 24CBF5474CFD1E2F
gpg: key 24CBF5474CFD1E2F: public key "OpenPrinting (OpenPrinting Key) " imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1

But then when I run update I get this:
W: GPG error: http://www.openprinting.org/download/printdriver/debian lsb3.2 Release: The following signatures were invalid: F8897B6F00075648E248B7EC24CBF5474CFD1E2F

Any ideas ?

Comment: A workaround might be to trust the repository manually: `deb [trusted=yes] http://www.deb-multimedia.org jessie main`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To everyone who also got confused like I did since there has not been an answer here and I have figured it out a while ago now. 
The answer is simple: There is no open printing for Ubuntu 18 and above* (*as far as I know for future versions) 
Instead the drivers are installed already and if you are missing any then simply search for them with

```
sudo apt-cache search printer*
```

This is how I found all the drivers I needed.